# Android NDK: read file from assets inside of shared library

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries, android-assets

In my app I have to pass a file from **assets** folder to **shared library**.
I cannot do it with use of jni right now.
I'm using precompiled shared library in my project, in which I have hardcoded path to my file, but I'm getting error *"No such file or directory"*.
So in my **.apk** file I have **.so** file in *libs/armeabi-v7a* folder and my file in */assets* folder.

I have tried to do it like this:

```
char *cert_file = "/assets/cacert.cert";
av_strdup(cert_file);
```

And some other paths, but it doesn't work.

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can simply use the AAssetManager class in C++.

Basically you need to:

- During the init of you library get a pointer on: `AAssetManager* assetManager`
- Use it to read your file:

  ```
  // Open your file
  AAsset* file = AAssetManager_open(assetManager, filePath, AASSET_MODE_BUFFER);
  // Get the file length
  size_t fileLength = AAsset_getLength(file);

  // Allocate memory to read your file
  char* fileContent = new char[fileLength+1];

  // Read your file
  AAsset_read(file, fileContent, fileLength);
  // For safety you can add a 0 terminating character at the end of your file ...
  fileContent[fileLength] = '\0';

  // Do whatever you want with the content of the file

  // Free the memoery you allocated earlier
  delete [] fileContent;
  ```

You can find the [official ndk documentation here](http://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group___asset.html).

> Edit:
>   To get the AAssetManager object:
>
> - In a native activity, you main function as a paramater **android_app* app**, you just need to get it here: app->activity->assetManager
> - If you have a Java activity, you need so send throught JNI an instance of the java object AssetManager and then use the function [AAssetManager_fromJava()](http://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group___asset.html#gadfd6537af41577735bcaee52120127f4)

Answer (score 3):

Your assets are packaged into your apk, so you can't refer to them directly during runtime like in the sample code you provided. You have 2 options here:

- Process the assets as an input stream, using

`Context.getAssets().open('cacert.cert')`

- Copy out your asset to a local file in your files dir, and then reference the filename of the copied file.

Comment: First option will not work for me now.
What about second - to which location should I put this file so I will be able to access it from .so lib?

Comment: Any actual file system location - internal storage, external, etc - obviously with all of the usual tradeoffs.  I believe there are also ways of accessing an asset from native code, but it's not simply a "file".

Comment: So I have to use absolute path?
Thanks, guys, I'll try it.

Comment: Unclear what you mean.  If you mean a copy you create as an actual file, then yes you need to either hand the native code a path it can use or a file descriptor.  If you mean the asset itself, it does not have a path because it is not a file (though can still be accessed by special means).

Comment: Context has a getFilesDir() method to get your files dir. I recommend using this instead of hardcoding paths to your app's data dir:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()

Comment: If this answered your question, you can mark this as an answer.

Comment: Actually you can access in the assets in the assets folder from the ndk ... (See my answer below)

Comment: Bundled assets do not have a file path. If the goal is to do file I/O to the asset in native C/C++ code, the only information that the main app can propagate to the JNI function is the `am` variable here  `AssetManager am = this.getContext().getAssets();`. The C/C++ code shall receive this `am` variable and continue the works from there. Eventually, the file I/O in C/C++ will have this line: `int nread = AAsset_read(asset,buf, length);`.  But before that, you need this: `int fd = AAsset_openFileDescriptor(asset, &offset, &length);` the `fd` if less than zero means asset is compressed.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of the answer by @Sistr , I used `getBuffer` along with `AASSET_MODE_BUFFER` (instead of `AAsset_read`).

However, I was trying to write the buffer to an `ofstream`. I got signal crashes using the `<<operator`:

```
ofstream myStream(<some file>, ios_base::binary);
auto buffer = AAsset_getBuffer(asset);
myStream << buffer;
```

I presume this is because the buffer pointer points to the asset without a `NULL` character at the end (I was reading a text asset; [Android source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/f3c204c6fccdc6050fe7bb2239043d5257956e6e/libs/androidfw/Asset.cpp#920)). Using the `write` function worked:

```
ofstream myStream(<some file>, ios_base::binary);
auto buffer = AAsset_getBuffer(asset);
myStream.write((char *)buffer, AAsset_getLength(asset));
```

This is because the `<<operator` does not have to call `strlen` to find out how many characters to write since it is explicitly given by `AAsset_getLength`.