# Android NDK accessing XML file

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk, android.mk

I am trying to build a lib written in C++. This lib uses OpenCV and needs to access some xml files for face part recognition. Somehow the file access isn't given and I get an error when running

```
CascadeClassifier faceCascade.load(faceCascadeFile);
```

I get an error at this point, because the file cannot be opened. The xml files should be contained in the OpenCV lib which is included via **Android.mk**

```
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
include ./jni/opencv/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
```

I also tried copying the .xml files into my jni folder and including them in my Android.mk

```
LOCAL_MODULE           := usit
LOCAL_SRC_FILES        := gfcf.cpp haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml haarcascade_mcs_eyepair_big.xml haarcascade_mcs_nose.xml
```

Still I don't get access to this file. I tried to inspect the built lib, but couldn't find any way to see if the files are somewhere available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to push the file on the device, directly to the storage or with the assets.
Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742444/how-to-access-resources-like-sound-images-etc-directly-from-native-code-using) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317387/how-to-get-file-in-assets-from-android-ndk).

If you choose to push the file on the storage, you can easily access it with:

```
string faceFile = "/sdcard/Download/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml";
CascadeClassifier classifier;
classifier.load(faceFile);
```

Comment: Yeah I added the files to the assets and copied them to my internal storage.